# document.getElementByClassName not working together with for-loop

Tags: javascript, css, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to make it so only some specific boxes get padding on the left and right but the code doesn't pass the "getElementByClassName"-part. I get the alert "Test1" but not "Test2" so the problem is somewhere on that line I think.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >

var numProducts = $('.product').length;
for(var i = 1;i<numProducts;i++){
    var x = (i+1)/3;
    
    if(x%1=0){  
        alert("test1");
        var box = document.getElementByClassName('product')[i-1];
        alert("test2");
        box.style.paddingRight ="30px";
        box.style.paddingLeft="30px";
    }
}

</script>
```

I get the right values from numProducts, i and x so I don't think they are the problem. What am I supposed to do? Thanks

Comment: typo - should be `getElementsByClassName`, with an "s"

Comment: `x%1=0` is an assignment and _not_ a comparison!

Answer (score 0):

What you expected should be `document.getElementsByClassName` rather than `document.getElementByClassName`.

Comment: while this is correct, you have more than enough reputation to know that putting an answer that just puts out a typo is unhelpful. Just vote to close it, and if you're feeling generous (I try to), explain the typo in a comment

Comment: @acrazing Omg that was so simple. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

The following is my version of your script. I would recommend that you actually *use* jQuery, as you have clearly loaded it already. And using jQuery means that something like `document.quersSelectorAll()` is not needed anymore.

```js
$('.product').each(function(i){
  i%3==2 && $(this).addClass("padded")
})
```

```css
.padded {padding-right:30px;
     padding-left:30px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">a</div>
<div class="product">b</div>
<div class="product">c</div>
<div class="product">d</div>
<div class="product">e</div>
<div class="product">f</div>
<div class="product">g</div>
<div class="product">h</div>
<div class="product">i</div>
```